# What is the difference between << and += while injecting elements to Hash.new([])?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

This code:

```
[{:id => 1,:key => 3},{:id => 2,:key => 4},{:id => 3, :key => 5}].
     inject(Hash.new([])){|h,i| h[i[:key]] << i; h}
```

returns:

```
{}
```

While this:

```
[{:id => 1,:key => 3},{:id => 2,:key => 4},{:id => 3, :key => 5}].
     inject(Hash.new([])){|h,i| h[i[:key]] += [i]; h}
```

returns:

```
{3=>[{:id=>1, :key=>3}, {:id=>3, :key=>3}], 4=>[{:id=>2, :key=>4}]}
```

Why doesn't the first case work same way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, you are modifying the array that is returned as the default of the hash, but that array is not defined as the value to the hash, and is thrown away.

In your second example, you are modifying the default array as well as assigning the result as the value to the hash by the method `Hash#[]=`. Notice that `foo += bar` is syntax sugar for `foo = foo + bar`, which means that `hash[foo] += bar` is the same as `hash[foo] = hash[foo] + bar`.

Comment: so in short, << doesnt create a new array. and it should get created to define hash element.